# How to find corresponding values for corresponding lists in python?

Tags: python, list, statistics, tuples, mean

I am working on a final project for my programming class, and I'm having trouble comparing lists to find how to find hourly statistics (mean and standard deviation). What was given, was a years worth of call data and the time it was received, and what I need to do is figure out the statistics of each day. So I have two lists, one of the day of the year, and one of the time in military hours, how would I create a list of each daily call data?
Example:

```
day_list = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
time_list = [0100,1200,1300,0010,1000,2040,1202,1346,2100]
```

So what the day list is, is each number corresponds to the day in the year. (1 = January first, 2 = January second, 3 = January third, and so on. It goes all the way to 365.) And each time value corresponds to the same place to day_list (0100 goes with 1, 0010 goes with 2, and 1346 goes with 3). What I want to do is create a new list, so that I can find the average and standard deviation for every day. And again, the values should correspond with placement. Example:

```
mean = [866, 1016, 1549]
```

So the new list should have 365 values, as the hourly average per day.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine both lists with `zip`, group the data for each day with `groupby` and finally calculate the mean of the daily values using the standard library `statistics` module `mean` function.

```python
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean

day_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
time_list = [100, 1200, 1300, 10, 1000, 2040, 1202, 1346, 2100]

combined = zip(day_list, time_list)
grouped = groupby(combined, lambda x: x[0])

mean_values = []
for day, results in grouped:
    print("Day: %d" % day)
    daily_values = [r[1] for r in results]
    print(daily_values)
    mean_values.append(mean(daily_values))

print(mean_values)
```